# Number of possible functions

Tags: integration, functions, definite-integrals

> The number of possible continuous functions $f(x)$ defined on $[0,1]$ for which $I_1 = \int_0^1 f(x)dx=1$, $I_2 = \int_0^1 xf(x)dx= a$ , $I_3=\int_0^1 x^2 f(x)dx= a^2$ is/ are?

I have seriously no idea how to attempt this problem and find the number of functions. I was trying some integration by parts for I2, I3 but that really didn't help.

Comment: Do we require $f$ to be continuous?

Comment: @Sambo Edited...

Answer (score 4):

Hint. Note that if there is one such $f$ then also $f(x)+tP(x)$ works for any real $t$ where
$$P(x)=3(x-1/2)-20(x-1/2)^3$$
because $\int_0^1 P(x)dx=\int_0^1 xP(x)dx=\int_0^1 x^2P(x)dx=0$.

In order to find one example of $f$, consider a quadratic polynomial $A+Bx+Cx^3$, then solve the system
$$\begin{cases}
\int_0^1 f(x) dx=1\\
\int_0^1 xf(x) dx=a\\
\int_0^1 x^2f(x) dx=a^2
\end{cases}$$
which is the linear with respect to $A$, $B$ and $C$.

Comment: How did you come up with $P$?

Comment: I considered a polynomial of $A(x-1/2)+B(x-1/2)^3$ which is "odd" with respect the midpoint $x=1/2$.

Answer (score 3):

There is an infinite number of functions $g$ such that:
$$\int_0^1 g(x) dx=\int_0^1 x g(x) dx=\int_0^1 x^2 g(x) dx=0$$
(for example orthogonal polynomials) and if $f$ is a solution and $g$ such that all the above integral are $0$ then $f+g$ is also $0$.

So the result is either $0$ or an infinite number of functions.

To show that there exist at least one solution you can consider:
\begin{align}
\phi: \mathbb R_2[X] \to \mathbb R^3\\
P \mapsto \left(\int_0^1 P(x) dx, \int_0^1 x P(x)dx , \int_0^1 x^2P(x) dx\right)
\end{align}
and use any linear algebra method (for example write the matrix) to show that this linear application is bijective.

Comment: please see the edit